# Analytic continuation of a certain Dirichlet series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analyticity, dirichlet-series

Is there an elementary way to analytically continue

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}$$

to the entire complex plane? It is not hard to see (by grouping terms in pairs and using the mean value theorem) that it converges for $\Re(z)>0$.

I realize there is a vast literature on Dirichlet series that almost certainly answers this with some general theorem. However, this sum appears as a [qualifying exam question](http://web.math.princeton.edu/generals/complex13.pdf) (1.43), so presumably there is a more direct method. For example, if the terms did not alternate, we could just take $(1-2^{-s})\zeta(s)$ and use the fact $\zeta(s)$ has a continuation to the entire plane.

Comment: $$ f(s) = -1+L(\chi,s) $$ where $\chi$ is the non-principal Dirichlet character $\pmod{4}$. See also [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation_%28L-function%29).

Comment: Finding the analytical continuation of a $L$-series can be done by modifying the 'standard' method of analytical continuating the $\zeta$-function. As Jack mentioned above your function is the $L$-series $f(s) = -1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s} = -1 + L(s,\chi)$ where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character satisfying $\chi(n+4)=\chi(n)$ with $\chi(1,2,3,4)=\{1,0,-1,0\}$. How to do this in practice is explained [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/analytic_continuations.pdf), see page 6.

Comment: @Potato: Winther uses summation by parts while I used integration by parts (just see below), but the method is essentially the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming $\text{Re}(s)>0$ we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)^s x^{2n}\,dx\\&=&-\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)^s \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\,dx\\&=&-\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^s}{e^t(1+e^{2t})}\,dt\end{eqnarray*} $$
and we may use integration by parts to find an analytic continuation over $\text{Re}(s)>-1$.

After that, we just have to repeat the process.